# Redux: State is only being updated in one place

Tags: reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux, I am trying to update state through props in my Survey Component.

In my console.log, the state in my reducer is being updated, but my app state is staying the same.

in my Router.js

```
const intialState = {
  currentQuestionId: 1,
}

function reducer(state = intialState, action) {
  console.log('reducer', state, action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        currentQuestionId: state.currentQuestionId + 1,
      }
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {
        currentQuestionId: state.currentQuestionId - 1,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Route path="/survey/:surveyName" component={CNA} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Provider>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

in Survey.js

```
class Survey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentQuestionId: 1,
    }

  }

  previousQuestion = () => {
    this.props.decrement()
  }

  nextQuestion = () => {
    this.props.increment()
  }


  render() {
    const { currentQuestionId } = this.state
    const { questions } = this.props
    return (
      <SurveyContainer>
        {console.log('surveyState', currentQuestionId)}
        <Question
          data={questions.find(q => q.id === currentQuestionId)}
        />
        <ButtonContainer>
          {currentQuestionId > 1 && (
            <Button type="button" onClick={this.previousQuestion}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
          <Button type="button" onClick={this.nextQuestion}>
            Next
          </Button>
        </ButtonContainer>
      </SurveyContainer>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment,
  decrement,
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentQuestionId: state.currentQuestionId,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Survey)
```

My console.log

```
reducer {currentQuestionId: 5} {type: "INCREMENT"}
SurveyState 1
```

So it seems that my reducer is, in fact, changing the state, however, my Survey Component does not seem to be aware of these changes.

Comment: Seems like `const { questions } = this.props` should be `const { questions, currentQuestionId } = this.props`, at least. React `this.state` and Redux state are 2 different things.

Comment: Ahhhh, yeah that was the problem, thank you